# javafx 2.2 pie chart colors not resetting

Tags: colors, javafx-2, pie-chart

When setting new data on an existing PieChart I notice the colours are not the same. 
(They cycle around the list of css colors, as if some internal counter is not being reset)

How do I start colors again at colour 0, without recreating the chart each time?

example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChartAdvancedPie extends Application {

PieChart pc = new PieChart();

private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    root.getChildren().add(pc);        
    pc.setAnimated(false);
    SetupData( );
    SetupData( ); //comment this out to see first colours only
}

protected void SetupData() {        
   ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();        
   data.add(new PieChart.Data("Slice", 1));
   data.add(new PieChart.Data("Slice", 2));
   data.add(new PieChart.Data("Slice", 3));
   pc.getData().clear();
   pc.setData( data );              
}

@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A hack to retain the color ordering is to add 8 - size mod 8 more items before clearing, but I'm sure there's an easier way (or I'm adding the data wrong)

```
int rem = 8-(pieChartData.size() % 8 );
for ( int i=0; i< rem; i++ ) {                        
   controller.FeatureChart.getData().add(new PieChart.Data("dummy", 1)); 
}                    
controller.FeatureChart.getData().clear();
//... add items again
```

Comment: Nice hack! I have the problem. I think the JavaFX just isn't mature enough for all these little bugs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the colors is currently not possible. The field used for the color index is declared private in PieChart and there is no official way to modify it.

However, if the environment allows this, one can fix it with reflection. Modify the `SetupData` method as follows:

```
protected void SetupData() {        
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();        
    data.add(new PieChart.Data("Slice", 1));
    data.add(new PieChart.Data("Slice", 2));
    data.add(new PieChart.Data("Slice", 3));
    //   pc.getData().clear();
    try {
        Class<PieChart> cls = PieChart.class;
        Field f = cls.getDeclaredField("defaultColorIndex");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.setInt(pc, 0);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pc.setData( data );
}
```

Don't use it.

If you must:

The `f.setAccessible(true)` allows setting private fields. This may fail and in reasonably well configured setups it will fail. If your application is a little desktop tool, it may work. Also you may like to check the java version before doing this and enable the code only for the versions for which you know that it works. (Some "temporary" tools turn out to be used in production for the next 10..20 years.)